# Photoshop multi-layered smart object file–need help converting into.gif

Tags: adobe-photoshop

For a web project, I've created a multilayered file that contains smart object glyphs. It is basically a PSD with a white background file and maybe 20 or so different smart objects placed on different layers. What I've done thus far in order to create the graphics is to highlight the eyeball and save the image for web.

Due to a last-minute background change, I need to now alter the white background and the corresponding glyph color. I was wondering if there is a way to automate this process so that each layer is saved as a.gif with the new background color. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I haven't found a simple answer yet–but was wondering if there is an easy way to color/change the color of the Smart object??

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to save this images *without* background (as long as the background is solid color), that is as images with information about transparency (alpha channel). If you'd do that from the start, you woudn't have to re-save them now.

Also I recommend you to drop the GIF format and use PNG instead. PNG allows you to have alpha channel with more than simply opaque/transparent values. Besides PNG files tend to be smaller than analogous GIFs. Mostly it's not a dramatic difference, but still :).

As for the automation of the process three things come to my mind:

1. Write a script to do that
2. Distribute your images on bigger canvas and use “Slices” to mark regions to save with “Save for Web”
3. If “you're Mac” you can take a look at http://macrabbit.com/layercake/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am on a Mac so I will check out layer cake.My problem usually writing script/actions is that I seem to always stall around the save as optimize for web section. Are there any useful scripts that I could lift or adjust slightly to save layers  independently instead of manually. You just save some time.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know any ready made scripts to solve your problem :(. If I was in your shoes, I'd consider writing one myself – hence the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

take the time to remove the background from each smart layer (you will need to convert back to raster), but overall this should not be a long process. when you have each layer on a transparent ground, you can use whatever you want for the background color as bottom layer of the file, and ever after easily change it.

To save turn off all but the current layer and the background color Ctrl Shift Alt S for Save for Web and devices. Here you can decide PNG or GIF, fill in all the appropriate settings. The settings will 'stick', so next Ctrl, shift, Alt S the same settings will be there and you'll only need to hit ok twice.

Almost as fast as having an action set up.